# Get attribute's Node parent

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to remove attribute from XML document by this attribute's XPath.
Everything should be done with Java.
I was able to find attribute's Node using the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("input.xml"));

XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("//div[@id='1']/@id");

Node myNode = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

My idea was to get attribute's node parent and after that call the removeChild method passing attribute's node as argument.

```
myNode.getParentNode().removeChild(myNode);
```

Unfortunately according to the API documentation attribute nodes have no parent.

How do I get the parent of an attribute Node?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like the appropiate DOM method is

```
((Attr) myNode).getOwnerElement()
```

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Attr.html#getOwnerElement()

> The `Element` node this attribute is
>   attached to or `null` if this attribute
>   is not in use.

Comment: Of course, they can't name it "Attribute" they have to name it "Attr".  Thanks Java.

Comment: @Michael The name Attr doesn't come from java. It comes from a language agnostic spec that java implements.

Comment: @Gunslinger You mean, there's a reason?  Thanks for robbing me of my righteous indignation.

Comment: @Michael haha... :-) I found this when I wondered why this API didn't support streams. Same reason.